Electronjs + Sequelize + SQLITE3 + VITE
I can't load extra file in main process.
I'm trying to use sequlieze and sqlite3 with electronjs but this error blocking me.
How can i fix this?
Thank you.
Error: Cannot find module './database/models/index.js'
Require stack:
- C:\www_desktop\cantar_v2\.vite\build\main.js

Main process:
"use strict";
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("node:path");
if (require("electron-squirrel-startup")) {
  app.quit();
}
const db = require("./database/models/index.js");
console.log(db);
const createWindow = () => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1500,
    height: 800,
    icon: "/src/assets/images/logo.svg",
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });
  {
    mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:5173");
  }
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

Files Structure:


In the last few days, I faced the same problem. After almost a week of trying everything on the internet from different resources, I finally found the solution. You should place your database folder in the resources folder and import it from there. That's it for me to solve this frustrating problem.

How could I do this exactly? Thank you
